# Windows Application Web service not working

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have upgraded my asp.net application from framework 2.0 to 4.0 and with this stated I am also running one web service which is in framework 2.0.

On deploying to the server, I am not able to get the output of the web service while application is running alright

Do I need to upgrade the version of web service too?
 And any change in app.config file required?

Comment: Need additional details.  For instance, is the application and the service running in the same IIS site?

Comment: yes..it lies in the same IIS site

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way forward is going to be to upgrade the web service to v4.x as well.  Each application pool can only be tied to a single version of the .Net framework.  It is technically possible to host a 2.x application inside of a 4.x site, but it will save a lot of trouble in the long term to standardize on a single version of the framework.

As [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329554(v=vs.100).aspx) describes:

> If an IIS Web application that targets the .NET Framework 3.5 or
>   earlier is nested inside an IIS Web application that targets the .NET
>   Framework 4, the compiler might report errors when it compiles the
>   nested application. This is because Web.config files inherit settings
>   from files that are higher in the configuration file hierarchy.

If you don't want to upgrade the service, your best bet is to prevent web.config inheritance.  [This blog post](http://blogs.iis.net/steveschofield/archive/2009/09/19/control-web-config-inheritance-with-iis-7-asp-net-options.aspx) has details on a few different ways to accomplish this.